# Networkx: difference between showing and saving graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I try to do some manipulation with graph, so I need to save that.
But I have a problem: showing plot looks well, but saving looks awful.
It's showing plot (`plt.show()`)
[image: showing]
And it's saving plot
[image: saving]

I use code

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
G.add_nodes_from(G.nodes(), color='red')
color = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'color')
values = [color.get(node, 0.5) for node in G.nodes()]
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, G.nodes(), node_size=10, node_color=values, cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow'))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.2)
plt.savefig("model2/05_1/1" + ".png")
```

I try to add `dpi` to `plt.savefig` but it doesn't help.
How can I save picture in the format, like it shows?

Comment: how is it if you save as .pdf?

Comment: @Joel I save in png because I need to create an animation

Comment: I'm still interested in knowing how it looks if you save as a .pdf.

Comment: @Joel, I have tried that, it looks like a saving png

Comment: As can be seen from the pictures, the dpi in both cases is the same; however the figure size differs. The problem is, with only the code given in the question, this problem is not reproducible, so we cannot find out why figure size differs. If you want, you can provide more information about how and where you run the code and also a [mcve] in order to get further help.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I use IDE PyCharm and `G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(128, 0.05)`. Thats all code that I use.

Comment: When I run the code in spyder both the plotting window and the produced png have exactly the same size, see [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V0Tv.png). You must have  set  a different figure size somewhere (deliberately or by accident).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, there are not difference, if you don't open showing plot and saving plot on the full screen. But it you open both, quality of showing plot is higher than saving plot

Comment: Sorry, this is completely unclear. You need to be precise in your statements. (You may want to use more sentences, structuring elements like, case A, case B etc., and less 'if' clauses). You may also simply edit your question instead of writing comments below it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I need to save fig in high quality and big size. If you enlarge showing plot( fullscreen) you will get the best high quality image. But if you save the plot and also try to enlarge that you will get awful image. I need to get image like fullscreen showing plots, but number of that is too big and it's uncomfortable to enlarge every showing graph and next save that. And i need to find a way to save plot in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you simply want a larger figure. The figure size can be set e.g. via the`figsize` argument of `plt.figure`. You may also increase the dpi for higher output quality.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,9))
# ... your code
plt.savefig(__file__ + ".png", dpi=360)
```